# making text files containing list of files in different directories with random name in bash

Tags: bash

I have a script which makes some `files in pair` (all the resulting files have either `R1` OR `R2` in the file name) and then put each pair in a separate directory with `random name` (every time will be different and I cannot predict). for example if I have 6 files, 3 files would be `file_R1.txt` or `file_R2.txt` but in pair like this example:

```
s1_R1.txt and s1_R2.txt
s2_R1.txt and s2_R2.txt
s3_R1.txt and s3_R2.txt
```

In this example I will have 3 directories  (one per pair of files). I want to make 2 text file (`d1.txt`  and. `d2.txt`) containing above file names. In fact, `d1.txt` will have all the files with `R1` and `d2.txt` will contain all the files with `R2`. To do so, I made the following short `bash` code but it does not return what I want. Do you know how to fix it?

```
For file in /./*R*.txt;
do;
    touch "s1.txt"
    touch "s2.txt"
    echo "${fastq}" >> "s1.txt"

done
```

Comment: Your bash script is not syntactically correct.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : why

Comment: `For` instead of `for`, a semi-colon after `do`. You can check all this yourself by trying to execute it or by copy-pasting in to [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : yes these are I know. for after typing and space became For but in terminal is for. I meant in the question, how can I change the code to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Weird question, not sure I get it, but for your d1 and d2 files:

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name "*R1*" -print >d1.txt
find . -type f -name "*R2*" -print >d2.txt
```

- `find` is used since you have files under different sub-directories.
- Using `>` ensures the text files are emptied out if they already exist.

**Note** the code you put in your question is not valid `bash`.

Comment: I think that is about as close as anything I was thinking. May want to point out `-print` can be omitted as that is the default operation for `find` (doesn't hurt, just don't want OP to think it is magic or something) May also explain that `.`, the starting directory, should be the directory that contains the 3-directories containing the pairs in the OP's example.